# Negative (te-form) + しまう

Tags: て-form, conditionals

I'm translating a song and came across this line:

> > 感じなくなっちゃえばいい

At first I thought it was:

感じる in negative te-form + しまう in conditional ば form + いい

But I think there's something wrong or something I'm ignoring. If I rewrite the sentence the way I think it is, it would be like:

> > 感じる　--->  感じなくて
> >
> > ~てしまえば --->  ~ ちゃえば
> >
> > いい

So my guess would be :

感じなくちやえばいい

Why is there a 'なっ' before 'ちやえば'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you noticed, if that were the 感じる in negative te-form, it would be 感じなくて as opposed to 感じなくな. That's why in reality it's 感じる + なくなる in te-form. Note that なくなる is the adverbial form of ない + なる.

> 感じる　--->  感じ
>
> なくなる ---> なくなって
>
> ~てしまえば --->  ~ ちゃえば
>
> いい

Comment: Thanks! Just one final question: Verb + なくなる means 'to stop doing Verb'?

Comment: @Chrollo It's more like `to become not` something, so in this case it would be similar to  `to lose feeling`. – Ringil 5 mins ago